# Custom Movie Slider with rectangle corners

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am trying to create a Slide for movie like this, I had achieved this effect by showing Slider and progress view showing at same location, but now the problem is how i can remove rounded corner effect from slider and progress view. Any help

[image]

Comment: please post the code...have you added the corner using UIBezierPath?

Comment: This is what i want to create